# Wicket: (how) can I associate an AjaxCheckBox to the CheckGroupSelector?

Tags: ajax, checkbox, wicket

I have a problem similar to this question: [Wicket: can Checkgroup be Ajax enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988905/wicket-can-checkgroup-be-ajax-enabled)

I'm using a ListView where each Item has a checkbox. I also have a "select all" checkbox. I am using a `CheckGroup`, `CheckGroupSelector` and `Check` and everything works great. Now there is a new requirement to change the state on some other controls on the page when the checkboxes are updated.

Nicktar's suggestion in the above linked question was the first that came to my mind, too, but I haven't been able to find out how it is possible to use `AjaxCheckBox` with `CheckGroup`/`CheckGroupSelector`. According to the doc you have to use `Check`.

But in [this mail from 2008](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/wicket-users/200807.mbox/%3C23eb48360807221008g407b1ed8ue01ac84716d18f9b@mail.gmail.com%3E), Igor Vaynberg also states that it is possible to use `AjaxCheckBox` in a `CheckGroup`.

I tried it with just replacing where I used `Check` with the `AjaxCheckBox`, but it didn't work, the `CheckGroupSelector` didn't find the checkboxes anymore.

I also looked into using the `onSelectionChanged` method in `CheckGroup`, but I'd like to avoid using this as it triggers another roundtrip to the server, as far as I understood.

Can someone give me a hint? Or is there another nice solution for this?

By the way, I'm using Wicket 1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you add an [`AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/form/AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior.html) to the `CheckGroup` ?

From `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior`'s JavaDoc:

> NOTE: This behavior does not work on Choices or Groups use the AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior for that.

[`AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/form/AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior.html) is the behavior to use with `CheckGroup`s and `RadioGroup`s. If you used an `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` with the `onchange` event, you'd run into [this bug](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-193-onchange-does-not-fire-properly.html) with IE 
. `AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior` handles this properly, [adding `onclick` event handlers](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.8/org/apache/wicket/ajax/form/AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior.java#63) to each of the `Check`s in the `CheckGroup`.

As a side note, what Igor stated in that mail, is that `CheckBox` can be replaced with `AjaxCheckBox`, not `Check`. `AjaxCheckBox` is nothing more than a convenience subclass of  `CheckBox` with an `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onclick")`, as [the sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/markup/html/form/AjaxCheckBox.java) show.

Comment: I didn't know about `AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior`. Thanks, it worked!

Comment: About Igor's mail: They were talking about `CheckGroup` in the mails before, so I guessed it was related. Maybe I assumed to much. Thanks for making that clear for me!

Comment: Be aware that clicking "Select all" causes `AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior` to be triggered for every checkbox in the group.